# Install paclets into $BaseDirectory on multi-user system

Tags: packages, paclets

`PacletInstall` will install paclets into the `$UserBaseDirectory` by default. How can we install them in `$BaseDirectory` so that all users on the system will have access?  Is this currently possible?

This is an important consideration if your package is expected to be installed on centrally managed multi-user systems (e.g. HPC clusters). This is not merely a theoretical situation. I know that [MATLink](http://matlink.org/) was installed this way on more than one site.

---

**Update:** It is not clear that system-wide paclets are well supported at this moment, even though the basics seem present in the paclet manager.  My conclusion is that at this moment it is better to avoid using paclets for system-wide installations.

Comment: It should be possible as the paclet manager sources use both a `$userRepositoryDir` and a `$sharedRepositoryDir`.

Comment: You can `Block` the `$userRepositoryDir` with `$BasePacletsDirectory/Repository`. Worked for me. Although `PacletFind` freaks out a little bit and returns the paclet twice.

Comment: Yep, I see that's what Kuba does too with `WithPacletsRepository`: https://github.com/kubaPod/MPM/blob/master/MPM/MPM.m

Comment: @b3m2a1 and Szabolcs, yes but so far I didn't have problems with this and `Get` or `PacletInformation` respect the most specific repository at the end. Otoh I won't bet my hand on that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I've pointed out [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39839225#39839225), on Linux it might be problematic to simply `Block` the `$userRepositoryDir` as you will need root-access for that in the default installation. No matter how you do this, you need to ensure that you can write there if you want to make it consistently working for all operating systems.

To the best of my knowledge, there is currently no easy way to install a paclet for all users automatically. What you want is to install a paclet in the `` PacletManager`Package`$sharedRepositoryDir `` but this option is not exported. When you call `PacletInstall` it will call `` PacletManager`Manager`Private`installPacletFromFileOrURL `` and there, the installation destination is hard-coded to `$userRepositoryDir`.

This is why `Block`ing this kind of works. I say "kind of" because after the paclet is unzipped into the destination, Mathematica rebuilds the internal information about installed paclets by calling `` PacletManager`Package`PCrebuild ``. If your destination is anything other than `$userRepositoryDir` or `$sharedRepositoryDir`, this shouldn't work, because the paclets to rebuild are again hard-coded as `"Collections" -> {"User"}`. Please look at the end of the definition of `installPacletFromFileOrURL`.

Therefore, the only sensible solution I see at the moment is

1. Check if you have write access to `` PacletManager`Package`$sharedRepositoryDir ``. If not, and you are on Linux, you might want to ask the user to re-run Mathematica with `sudo`.
2. `Block` the `$userRepositoryDir` as suggest by b3m2a1 and already used by Kuba.

Comment: One could run `PacletDirectoryAdd` in init.m for other locations. But so is with $Path for custom directories.

Comment: @Kuba Hmm, it's not clear to me what the side-effects are, but directories added with `PacletDirectoryAdd` go into the `"Extra"` paclet collection, while the ones installed with `PacletInstall` are stored in the `"User"` section.

Comment: I don't know either but do you anticipate problems? I use PacletDirectoryAdd for testing/running paclets directly from their development directories. So far didn;t have problems even if released versions where already PacletInstall-ed.

Comment: @Kuba When I see this right, Szabocls wants users to easily install his package with `PacletInstall` which is convenient since he can do this directly from the GitHub repo. If he does this, then the version is of the paclet is tracked in the `"User"` collection. If a different user opens the same Mathematica, he uses his own User-collection which has no idea about the installed paclet. When I see this right from looking at the code then a) the user that installed the Paclet (in a different dir with `Block`) has it tracked in "User". If he runs `PacletDirectoryAdd` that it is probably tracked..

Comment: twice. b) a different user who is opening the same Mathematica can use `PacletDirectoryAdd`. As I said, I'm not sure if there are any serious consequences. I merely point out that there are some glitches that might lead to weird behavior and one should look out them or intensively test the approach.

Comment: I don't think custom dir will be tracked just because we installed a paclet with Block, at least not after the kernel quit. Unless I missed something. And PacletDirectoryAdd could be in $BaseDirectory Kernel's init.m though I'm not sure how it is handled if many init.m-s are in stack.

Comment: @Kuba If I have time, I'm trying to come up with an example that shows what exactly I mean and if it introduces wrong behavior.

Comment: Ok, sorry if I didn't get your point :)

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issues, so i switched to the NPM like way of organising paclets.

[Wolfram Local Packages Manager](https://github.com/JerryI/wl-localpackages)

So it stores everything in the projects’s folder and keeps all paclets up to date according to github repos. That helped me a lot, since there is no need to guess if PacletInstall will figure out a new version.